# Wordpress keeps crashing my server

Tags: server, hosting, memory

I wonder whether anyone has experienced this, but every 5-10 clicks or so either in the admin panel or somewhere around navigating the website, my server crashes.

Would anyone know why this happens and how I can stop this from happening? I have a basic hosting, but I have been using the same hosting for years and nothing came even close to crashing that server so much.

EDIT:

Here are some server log errors:

```
[Sun Dec 08 05:59:31 2013] [error] [client 41.160.218.195] PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 16252928) (tried to allocate 19456 bytes) in /home/webadmin/glowingstart.com/html/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/header.php on line 52
[Sun Dec 08 09:58:32 2013] [error] [client 74.64.0.36] PHP Fatal error:  out of dynamic memory in yy_create_buffer() in /home/webadmin/glowingstart.com/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/inc/define.php on line 1449, referer: http://glowingstart.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=640&action=edit&message=6
[Mon Dec 09 16:16:59 2013] [error] [client 110.85.107.155] PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 15990784) (tried to allocate 19456 bytes) in /home/webadmin/glowingstart.com/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/social-media-feather/synved-option/addons/option-type-addon/option-type-addon.php on line 53, referer: http://glowingstart.com/look-business-partner/
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: Did you make sure you are not creating an Infinite Loop in one of your queries? What do your logs say and did you try increasing your max_memory_limit for testing purposes?

Comment: What do you mean in "my server crashes"?

Comment: I don't think I have anything like infinite loops because I didn't do anything custom. I am just using the very basic WP functionality.

Comment: @MarkKaplun the server just runs out of memory and crashes. I then have to go and start it again.

Comment: Disable all plugins and switch to the default theme. Does it still happen?

Comment: so you run your own vps and not on shared hosting?

Comment: I added the server errors to my original question.

Comment: You are running out of memory at between 15MB and 16MB. The minimum requirement for WordPress is 32MB (64MB for Multisite). Your server is severely short on memory, or your configuration is such that the memory is unavailable.